# Scala : statements are not executed in order

Tags: scala

I am learning `scala` I tried following program

```
package com.avdongre

object MyModule {
  def abs(n: Int): Int =
    if (n < 0) -n
    else n
  private def formatAbs(x: Int) = {
    val msg = "The absolute value of %d is %d"
    msg.format(x, abs(x))
  }

  def factorial(n: Int): Int = {
    def go(n: Int, acc: Int): Int =
      if (n <= 0) acc
      else go(n - 1, n * acc)
    go(n, 1)
  }
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit =    
    println(formatAbs(-42))
    println(factorial(5))

}
```

I get following output

```
120
The absolute value of -42 is 42
```

Why `factorial` is getting called first ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need curly braces around your body of `main`:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  println(formatAbs(-42))
  println(factorial(5))
}
```

What is happening is you have this (with corrected indentation for clarity):

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = 
  println(formatAbs(-42))

println(factorial(5))
```

Hence when the object `MyModule` gets initialized, the last statement of the body is `println(factorial(5))` which occurs *before* your `main` method.